# CSS - Select all elements descended from an element with a specific class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I select all the elements that are descended from an element with a specific class?

For example...I want all table cells (`td`) that are descended ONLY from a table that has a specific class.

Comment: `table.class td` would work..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships

Comment: In case you are confused as to why you're being downvoted, you've asked a question which is trivially easy to answer by searching google, and have posted no code [showing what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), which implies that you're not really invested into finding an answer for yourself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because author did do anything.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde, moderators did not close your question, the community voted to close your question. Please review the [faq], and try to avoid taking this personally. We're not trying to be jerks to you, we're trying to make sure that the content on [SO] maintains a consistent level of quality. I've asked questions that have gotten closed too. It sucks, but you either fix the question or delete it and move on.

Comment: Thanks @zzzzBov. I do take it too personally sometimes because it happens too frequently and with too much zeal and in too draconian and objective a manner. But you are right, I won't take it personally.

Comment: Although I still would like to know how this question is not about programming...

Comment: @RichardDesLonde The votes were on the "other" close type, where SalvadorDali had commented "This question appears to be off-topic because author did (sic) do anything."

Comment: As a moderator, I'm less interested in whether the OP took the closure personally and more incredulous at the fact that the first voter couldn't even bother to write a proper close reason, never mind that the rest of the close voters went with it anyway just to get the question closed.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you. I agree. Holding the question to a strict standard and then not following the standards for holding questions to standards is ridiculous.

Comment: I am upvoting here just to do something against that ridiculous downvote syndrome here. It seems you got an answer, which was quick and helped you. That's all what this site is about. I don't understand why you get downvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the CSS [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators):

```
.foo td
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for. Sometimes you can't google search if don't know the right keywords. I must be an idiot for not thinking of something so obvious as "descendant combinator".

Comment: @RichardDesLonde, "select all elements descended css" in google provided more than adequate results, and I pulled that from your title.

Comment: Yeah somehow I wasn't getting it. I tried a lot of things. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Upvote from my side. Short and good, and it helped the OP. that's what this site is about.